# C++ static object does not save array attribute value

Tags: c++, vivado, vivado-hls

I am working in C++ inside Vitis HLS from Xilinx. I am writing a simple buffer to perform the well know overlap and add algorithm (https://www.eetimes.com/fft-convolution-and-the-overlap-add-method/)

My code creates a static object (my buffer) and then works with a "sample-wise" approach.

The code I am using is the following (header + function to be synthesized + testbench):

**Overlapper_HLS.hpp:**

```
#include "ap_axi_sdata.h"
#include "hls_stream.h"
#include <ap_fixed.h>


#define IFFT_LENGTH 16
#define INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH 8
#define BUFFER IFFT_LENGTH - INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH

typedef ap_fixed<16,1> ap_fixed_data_type;

typedef struct {

    ap_fixed_data_type real_part;
    ap_fixed_data_type imaginary_part;

} my_data_struct;

typedef hls::axis<my_data_struct,0,0,0> pkt_t;

typedef hls::axis<my_data_struct,0,0,0> pkt_t_out;

class Overlapper {

private:
    ap_fixed_data_type IFFT_output_real[IFFT_LENGTH];
    ap_fixed_data_type IFFT_output_imaginary[IFFT_LENGTH];

    ap_fixed_data_type output_chunk_real[INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH];
    ap_fixed_data_type output_chunk_imaginary[INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH];

    ap_fixed_data_type buffer_real[BUFFER];
    ap_fixed_data_type buffer_imaginary[BUFFER];

    int counter;

public:
    Overlapper() {

        for(int i = 0; i<IFFT_LENGTH; i++){
            IFFT_output_real[i]= 0;
            IFFT_output_imaginary[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; i++){
            output_chunk_real[i]= 0;
            output_chunk_imaginary[i] = 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<BUFFER; i++){
            buffer_real[i]= 0;
            buffer_imaginary[i] = 0;
        }

        counter = 0;
    }

    void top_function(
        hls::stream<pkt_t> &input_signal_stream,
        hls::stream<pkt_t> &output_signal_stream) {
#pragma HLS PIPELINE
        pkt_t pkt_input_signal;
        pkt_t pkt_output_signal;
        float tmp =0;
        int i = 0;

        if(counter < IFFT_LENGTH){
            i = counter;
            input_signal_stream.read(pkt_input_signal);
            
            IFFT_output_real[i] = pkt_input_signal.data.real_part;
            IFFT_output_imaginary[i] = pkt_input_signal.data.imaginary_part;

            counter++;
            printf("printing counter: %d \n", counter);
            printf("printing i: %d \n", i);

            printf("printing input value: %f \n", pkt_input_signal.data.real_part.to_float());
            printf("printing value of IFFT_real: %f \n", IFFT_output_real[i].to_float());


        }
        else{
            //Buffer does not contain the previously stored values anymore, it is always 0.
            for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                printf("printing content of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[i].to_float());
            }

            for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                IFFT_output_real[i] += buffer_real[i];
                IFFT_output_imaginary[i] += buffer_imaginary[i];
                printf("checking buffer value before sum: %f \n", buffer_real[i].to_float());
                printf("checking sum result real: %f \n", IFFT_output_real[i].to_float());
                printf("checking sum result imaginary: %f \n", IFFT_output_imaginary[i].to_float());
            }

            for(int k=INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; k<IFFT_LENGTH; k++){
                buffer_real[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_real[k];
                buffer_imaginary[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_imaginary[k];
                printf("Printing value of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[k-BUFFER].to_float());

            }
            //Here it seems that the values in Buffer are stored correctly
            for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                printf("printing content of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[i].to_float());
            }

            for(int j=0; j<INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; j++){
                pkt_output_signal.data.real_part = IFFT_output_real[j];
                pkt_output_signal.data.imaginary_part = IFFT_output_imaginary[j];
                printf("printing output signal: %f \n", pkt_output_signal.data.real_part.to_float());
                output_signal_stream.write(pkt_output_signal);
            }
            counter = 0;

        }

    }

};

void overlapper(hls::stream<pkt_t> &input_signal_stream, hls::stream<pkt_t> &output_signal_stream);
```

**Overlapper_HLS.cpp:**

```
#include <overlapper_HLS.hpp>

void overlapper(hls::stream<pkt_t> &input_signal_stream, hls::stream<pkt_t> &output_signal_stream){
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE axis register port=input_stream
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE axis register port=output_stream
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_ctrl_none port=return
    static Overlapper bb;
    bb.top_function(input_signal_stream, output_signal_stream);
}
```

**testbench.cpp:**

```
#include <overlapper_HLS.hpp>

int main(){

    hls::stream<pkt_t> input_stream;
    hls::stream<pkt_t> output_stream;

    pkt_t input_data;
    pkt_t temp_output;
    float int_output, input_check;
    // pkt_t input_package_check

    input_data.data.real_part = 0.1;
    input_data.data.imaginary_part = 0.1;

    for(int i=0; i<32; i++){
        input_stream.write(input_data);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<34; i++){
        overlapper(input_stream, output_stream);
    }


    for(int i=0; i<16; i++){
        output_stream.read(temp_output);
        //printf("output_value: %f", temp_output.data.real_part.to_float());
        printf("output_value: %f \n", temp_output.data.real_part.to_float());

    }


    return 0;

}
```

My code works as expected, the only problem I have is that inside the `top_function()` of my `Overlapper` class, the `buffer_real` and `buffer_imaginary` arrays do not store values between different calls of the function.

In particular the problem is in the following lines of code:

```
else{
                //Here unfortunately the stored value is always 0! It seems like the values are "reset" between different calls of the function.
                for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                    printf("printing content of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[i]);
                }
    
                for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                    IFFT_output_real[i] += buffer_real[i];
                    IFFT_output_imaginary[i] += buffer_imaginary[i];
                    printf("checking buffer value before sum: %f \n", buffer_real[i].to_float());
                    printf("checking sum result real: %f \n", IFFT_output_real[i].to_float());
                    printf("checking sum result imaginary: %f \n", IFFT_output_imaginary[i].to_float());
                }
    
                for(int k=INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; k<IFFT_LENGTH; k++){
                    //Here I am saving the values I need inside my buffer
                    buffer_real[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_real[k];
                    buffer_imaginary[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_imaginary[k];
                    printf("Printing value of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[k-BUFFER].to_float());
    
                }
                //Once I assign the values in the previous for cycle, they seem to be stored correctly!
                for(int i=0; i<BUFFER; i++){
                    printf("printing content of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[i]);
                }
    
                for(int j=0; j<INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; j++){
                    pkt_output_signal.data.real_part = IFFT_output_real[j];
                    pkt_output_signal.data.imaginary_part = IFFT_output_imaginary[j];
                    printf("printing output signal: %f \n", pkt_output_signal.data.real_part.to_float());
                    output_signal_stream.write(pkt_output_signal);
                }
                counter = 0;
    
            }
```

I can not figure out why my `buffer_real` and `buffer_imaginary` seem to be reset between different calls, even if the object I created is static (in fact the variable counter is preserved between different calls of my `top_function()`)

**EDIT** : I am adding my output log

```
#### FIRST ROUND ######
printing counter: 1 
printing i: 0 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 2 
printing i: 1 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 3 
printing i: 2 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 4 
printing i: 3 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 5 
printing i: 4 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 6 
printing i: 5 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 7 
printing i: 6 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 8 
printing i: 7 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 9 
printing i: 8 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 10 
printing i: 9 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 11 
printing i: 10 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 12 
printing i: 11 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 13 
printing i: 12 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 14 
printing i: 13 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 15 
printing i: 14 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 16 
printing i: 15 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 

### SECOND ROUND ### 
printing counter: 1 
printing i: 0 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 2 
printing i: 1 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 3 
printing i: 2 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 4 
printing i: 3 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 5 
printing i: 4 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 6 
printing i: 5 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 7 
printing i: 6 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 8 
printing i: 7 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 9 
printing i: 8 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 10 
printing i: 9 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 11 
printing i: 10 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 12 
printing i: 11 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 13 
printing i: 12 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 14 
printing i: 13 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 15 
printing i: 14 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing counter: 16 
printing i: 15 
printing input value: 0.099976 
printing value of IFFT_real: 0.099976 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing first content of buffer: 0.000000 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
checking buffer value before sum: 0.000000 
checking sum result real: 0.099976 
checking sum result imaginary: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing second content of buffer: 0.000000 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
printing output signal: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976 
output_value: 0.099976
```

As you might notice my buffer has always 0 value (`printing second content of buffer: 0.000000`), however in the previous cycle where I save the values, it seems that they're stored correctly (`Printing value of buffer after saving values: 0.099976`).

Basically in the second "round" of printing the content of my buffer, it should be `0.099976` instead of `0`

Comment: Does the "Printing value of buffer" line appear? Does it look correct? Why are you sometimes logging it with `to_float()` and other times not? Do you _expect_ `buffer_real[i]` to work when interpreted as a `double` without calling `to_float()`?

Comment: i see they are per-Overlapper.  if you wanted them per process, add keyword static...

Comment: @Useless I fixed the code, I forgot to write .to_float() in some prints!

Comment: @Abel I thought about that, however the variable counter is stored correctly in "memory" when I call multiple times my function. Why does it work for counter and not for the arrays?

Comment: There _is_ only one `Overlapper` in this program, because it's `static` inside `overlapper()`. That part is fine. Now, when you log the values correctly ... does it work? Is it still wrong? Which output is correct and which is unexpected?

Comment: @Useless Even with the fixed code (it was wrong only here on stackoverflow) the output is still not correct. I am passing samples of value 0.1 as input. They are stored correctly inside ```IFFT_output_real```. Then I sum this array and ```buffer_real``` and I get 0.1 as output in ```output_chunk_real``` which is correct. Then I save the "last" part of ```IFFT_output_real``` inside ```buffer```, and I get 0.1 inside the buffer (which is correct).

Comment: @Useless Then the whole code is called again and performs the same operations. However now I expect to find 0.1 inside my ```buffer```, but what I get is 0! It seems that between the calls of my function, the stored values get lost.
I can not understand what is happening, because the printf immediately after this comment "//Once I assign the values in the previous for cycle, they seem to be stored correctly!" prints 0.1  (which is correct), however in the next call of my function  ```buffer ``` contains only zeros.

Comment: @Useless I hope it is clear now which is my problem!

Comment: Not really - you really need to show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and that output. Currently I'd just be guessing at all the intermediate values you've printed but not shown to us.

Comment: @Useless The code I provided is complete and meant to run. Unfortunately it is meant to run inside the Vitis HLS tool from Xilinx, but it is complete and runnable. I can add my log if needed

Comment: @Useless I added my log with some comments

Comment: @Useless I found the problem, I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was the usage of my `#define BUFFER IFFT_LENGTH - INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH` inside the indexing of the following code snippet:

```
 for(int k=INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH; k<IFFT_LENGTH; k++){
                    //Here I am saving the values I need inside my buffer
                    buffer_real[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_real[k];
                    buffer_imaginary[k-BUFFER] = IFFT_output_imaginary[k];
                    printf("Printing value of buffer: %f \n", buffer_real[k-BUFFER].to_float());
    
                }
```

It messes up the indexing because is substitutes `BUFFER` with `16 - 8` as it is, so my indexing becomes `8 - 16 + 8`, which is still 0 as intended, but probably it creates some problems because the number becomes negative if added sequentially.

Changing that line of code to `buffer_real[k-(BUFFER)] = IFFT_output_real[k];` solved my problem.

A better solution is using `constexpr` instead of a define:

```
#define IFFT_LENGTH 16
#define INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH 8
constexpr int BUFFER=IFFT_LENGTH - INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH;
```

Comment: It's generally suggested practice to wrap macro expressions in parenthesis, eg. `#define BUFFER (IFFT_LENGTH - INPUT_WINDOW_LENGTH)` for this reason. I mean, it's generally preferred to avoid macros where possible, so the constexpr is definitely better.